# React create element again on re-render

Tags: reactjs

I want a comment to be posted one after another but not exactly sure how to implement it. Right now, the new comment is replacing the old one. After reading some posts, I think this.props.children could be the answer but stil somewhat confused, so please let me know the best way to implement what I want to. Thanks.

Comment.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Display } from './Display';

export default class Comment extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { buttonClicked: false, count: 0 };
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }


    handleClick() {
      this.setState({ buttonClicked: true , count : this.state.count + 1 });
      console.log('Button clicked');
    }

    render() {
      const comment_form =(
        <div className="posts" >
           <input type="text" id="comment-box" name="comment" placeholder="Say something nice." />
           <button className="submit-button" type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Comment</button>
        </div>
      );
      
      if (this.state.buttonClicked) {
        return (
          <div>
            {comment_form}
            <Display commentNumber={this.state.count} /> 
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return (<div> {comment_form} </div>);
        } 
    }
}
```

Display.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

export class Display extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('display rendered');
    const comments = (
      <div className="display-comments">
        <p>Comment {this.props.commentNumber} :{ document.getElementById('comment-box').value }</p>
      </div>
    );
 
    return (
     <div>
       {comments}
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to keep track of the all the submitted comments in your state, not just the count. You should have an array called `comments` in your state, and each time the user submits a comment, you append the new comment to the array using `setState`. Here's the React docs for rendering lists of items: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Please post solutions below as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the map function to dynamically render the elements.
Link: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html